# How to assign session values form index.phtml in zend?? and How to create logout functionily with session in zend?

Tags: zend-framework, session-variables

I am trying to learn **Zend_session** with Login and Logout.I have used 2 controllers that are IndexController and DashboardController.My login function is present in **IndexController** and I have designed Login form in index.phtml and I want to save session values from index.phtml and want to forward it to next account page i.e **DashboardController.**

When user logins into account and goes to **DashboradController** it should be able to access values of Session which was created in **IndexContrller.**

My question is that how to assign session values from **index.phtml**?

My second question is that when user clicks on logout it should be **redircted to homepage and should not be able to account by pressing back button..How to implement it???**

Comment: Deal with sessions in the controller not in the views. Once logged in from the index/loginAction forward to DashboardController

Comment: It means that we can't access view's value in the controller?

Comment: ok can you help me in my second question?

Comment: Of course you can access view variables in the controller. But normally the logic should be all in your controller and the view is just to output the view-variables.

Comment: can u tell me a how to access view's value in controller